# Div Moving Around

Tags: html, css

Okay so I have been trying everything I can think of to get this div to stay where it is on any browser and I thought I would turn to you wonderful people to try to help me (I am sure its an easy fix that I have overlooked)

No matter what I do it seems to mess things up elsewhere.

I have tried to put all divs (and the body) into fixed position (and this seems to have worked to an extent)

I have also tried to make the whole page flex in the hope that if I allow flex to work then it will flex around the offending items.

I have literally spent 2 days bashing my head against a wall with this and I could really use another set of eyes on my code to show me where I am going wrong.

Thankyou so much for your responses

**I have updated my code to now run without images and with colours instead. I have managed to sort some of the issues out I was having but now when I move the page from bottom up the blue door shrinks**

```css
#opening {
  background-color: red;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.wrap {
  background-color: purple;
  background-position: fixed;
  min-height: 140px;
  max-height: 140px;
  max-width: 360px;
  min-width: 360px;
  color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  margin: 20vh;
  margin-left: 42%;
  padding: 30% 2% 0% 0%;
}

div.left {
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 34vh;
  max-height: 62vh;
  min-width: 34vh;
  min-height: 62vh;
  /* background-image:url("door.png") ; */
  background-position: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-left: 42.1%;
  margin-top: 12.5%;
  animation-name: open-left;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-easing-function: cubic-bezier(.06, .63, 0, 1);
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 10s;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes open-left {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(500) rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 20%;
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(500) rotateY(89deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 20%;
  }
}

button {
  background-color: #000000;
  max-width: 70%;
  max-height: 20;
  border: white;
  border-style: double;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-overflow: unset;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 1%;
}
```

```html
<body id="opening">

  <div class="wrap">
    <span class="animated rubberBand infinite"> 


    <div>
        <div>
            <button onclick="location.href = 'https://www.google.com';"class="button"> And the Gunslinger followed </button>
        </div>
    </div>
            
    </span>
    <div class="left">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**this gives me an output of this on a full screen**

[Full size page, no shrink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/td2Sz.jpg)

**and this is the output when I shrink the screen to the left**

[Div position moves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wygy.jpg)

Comment: I created a snippet for you, we can't really reproduce your problem. Please update it so that we can see what you are talking about. One note: position fixed for body doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Repo
https://github.com/KeiraJ87/website

Website
https://keiraj87.github.io/website/

Comment: that's a 404 link... also add all code that's needed to reproduce your issue to the quesion, don't link to another site.

Comment: That is all the code, there isn't anything else that interacts with those 2 pages apart from another html page which is fine :/

Comment: Images are also part of the code. If you can't link directly to them, then use dummy elements or dummy images. Just so that we can reproduce your issue and can see the wrong positioned "door".

Comment: okay I've swapped out images for colours to give a vague idea of whats happening

Comment: I have fixed the positioning issues with the background, wrap and the door itself, however the door still moves when page size is adjusted

Comment: Do you want the background image to be fixed size or scalable to fit the screen resolution?

Comment: I want everything to be fixed ideally, just so everything stays where it is no matter what size. I know thats not good practice (I usually make EVERYTHING responsive) but this is going against everything I know haha

Comment: `background-position: fixed` - that's not a thing. Fixing the background image happens via the `background-attachment` property.

Comment: _"I want everything to be fixed ideally"_ - then work with pixels instead of percentages and min-/max-widths, and center the container element with regard to the viewport, and let any overflow be cut off.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are after?

```css
html,
body {
  display: flex;
  background: #000 url('https://keiraj87.github.io/website/backg.png') top center no-repeat;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#door-wrap {
  height: 295px;
  width: 175px;
  margin: 150px auto 0 auto;
  perspective: 420px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

#door {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: url('https://keiraj87.github.io/website/door.png') top center no-repeat;
  background-size: 175px;
  animation: open-left 10s cubic-bezier(.06, .63, 0, 1) 0s 1 forwards;
  margin-left: -88px;
}

@keyframes open-left {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(0deg) translateX(88px);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(-85deg) translateX(88px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="door-wrap">
  <div id="door">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: YES YES YES YES!!!!! AMAZING thankyou So much, thats fantastic.

Comment: is there any way to make it full screen? or does that stop it responding properly?

Comment: Yes, you can make it full screen but in order to align the door overlay you would need to make that image the same size as the background so that they scale in tandom. You could do this by simply adding an area or alpha transparancy around the door image. You would then have to alter the 3d rotation so it rotates along the door's y axis.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I haven't ever used Alpha before

Comment: If you have photoshop. 1. Open background image. 2. Add door image as new layer. 3. Hide the background layer. 4. Save image as png. e.g https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-save-a-32-bit-PNG-in-Photoshop-CS5-with-alpha-channel